# how to Sort list of KeyValuePair in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to sort the value of list of Keyvluepair in vb.net
This is c# example which is working,

```
static int Compare1(KeyValuePair<string, string> a, KeyValuePair<string, string> b)
{
    return a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key);
}

postparamslist.Sort(Compare1);
```

But in vb its not working:-

```
Public Function Compare1(ByVal a As KeyValuePair(Of String, String), ByVal b As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) As Integer
    Return a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key)
End Function
```

Comment: Not able to call in VB.net

Comment: They're both the same, and the first one is not c#.

Comment: postparamslist.Sort(Compare1)

Comment: But not able call in VB.net

Comment: static int Compare1(KeyValuePair<string, string> a, KeyValuePair<string, string> b)
    {
        return a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key);
    }

Comment: How are you trying to use it? You would need to be calling `Array.Sort` or the `Sort` method of a generic `List` and pass a `Comparison` delegate that referred to that method.

Comment: tryed this _`postparamslist.Sort(Compare1)`_ in VB but it is giving error.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I'm not sure I understand what is being sorted.  Is the code in your post trying to simply order a KeyValuePair list according to the value of the Key?  Or is your code more complicated than a simple sort?